# How to statistically validate a Framework?

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, manova

I am creating a Framework, that has independent variables A and B. It has dependent variables C, D, E. F, G, as shown in the diagram. [Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYnQZ.png)

I understand that only after validating a Framework we can present it as a model or theory. I am not clear which statistical tools/techniques we need to use to validate the Framework, to ensure that the proposition between the independent and dependent variables are statistically correct.  Please provide the necessary directions to accomplish the same.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Structural Equation Modeling, but it seems like the kind of approach you're looking for. If I understand it correctly, it attempts to falsify these kinds of graphical models by testing their implied variance structures.

Comment: So do I understand that the Regression Analysis is the appropriate approach to validate the Framework? On the other hand, if r-square > .8, it will only tell us about the relationship between two dependent var are correlated. I am more curious about the 'validation' part.

Comment: Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I already offered one. I think it's unclear what you're asking from the title; I'm going to suggest a few edits that might improve visibility. Feel free to roll them back if you don't like them

Comment: I hope my question is straight forward now. I am looking to hear for an answer so that I may proceed.

Comment: Why are the arrows directional? If you mean something in the lines of causality then some light may be provided by tools such as Granger causality. Otherwise in statistics dependencies are not directional even though regression equations seem to suggest direction such as dependent variable and independent variables.

Comment: This is what I need to validate. At this stage, it is a proposition from literature reviews and theories. How do I validate (make sure that this supposition of my diagram is correct)?